# Why is curl using HTTP/1.1 rather than HTTP/2 on mac?

Tags: curl, http2, http-1.1

According to this https://curl.haxx.se/docs/http2.html

`Since 7.47.0, the curl tool enables HTTP/2 by default for HTTPS connections.`

Installing the latest version with homebrew and checking:

```
curl --version
curl 7.54.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0) libcurl/7.54.1 SecureTransport zlib/1.2.5
```

but running `curl` on an HTTP2 enabled URL (e.g. test with https://tools.keycdn.com/http2-test) I get:

```
curl -I http://www.google.co.uk 
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

and

```
curl --http2 -v http://www.google.co.uk
curl: (1) Unsupported protocol
```

Any idea why it's using HTTP/1.1 rather than HTTP/2?

Answer (score 8):

You can build curl to use one of many different TLS/SSL libraries, each of those has slightly different feature sets and offer slightly different conditions for curl to work with.

The curl you show in your question lists `SecureTransport` as the TLS library it was built to use, the macOS native TLS library.

Secure Transport simply does not provide the necessary means for curl to negotiate HTTP/2 over TLS - or at least it hasn't, as I've been told that the very latest version now supports ALPN so a future curl version should be able to do HTTP/2 over TLS even with Secure Transport.

In addition to the proper TLS negotiation, curl also needs to speak HTTP/2, which it does thanks using the venerable nghttp2 library so that's a second dependency that needs to be there for curl to be able to speak HTTP/2. With nghttp2 present, curl can actually speak HTTP/2 over plain-text HTTP even when the TLS library can't negotiate ALPN properly.

### Fix?

Later macOS versions ship curl built with libreSSL and HTTP/2 support built-in.

If you opt to instead rebuild curl with another TLS library, such as OpenSSL, GnuTLS or NSS it can speak HTTP/2 fine over HTTPS already today.

Comment: FYI the function to enable HTTP/2 negotiation in SecureTransport is `SSLSetALPNProtocols`. It's available on iOS 11+ and macOS 10.13+.

Comment: In the mean time, Apple has switched and now ships curl built to use libressl ...

Comment: Oh. Didn't know that. That's... surprising.

Answer (score 3):

With MacOS Sierra, this is how you can install an updated curl that supports HTTP2 by using OpenSSL instead of SecureTransport.

1. `brew reinstall curl --with-openssl --with-nghttp2`
2. `brew link curl --force`
3. Relaunch Terminal
4. `curl -V` should return something like this:

> curl 7.54.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin16.6.0) libcurl/7.54.1 OpenSSL/1.0.2l 
>   zlib/1.2.8 nghttp2/1.24.0 Release-Date: 2017-06-14 Protocols: dict
>   file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps  pop3 pop3s rtsp
>   smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp Features: IPv6 Largefile NTLM NTLM_WB
>   SSL libz TLS-SRP HTTP2  UnixSockets HTTPS-proxy

I should note that MacOS minor point updates sometimes overwrite the curl version being used. If that happens, simply re-run `brew link curl --force` and relaunch terminal to switch back to the homebrew HTTP2 enabled version.

Comment: Side note: macOS High Sierra comes with curl 7.54.0 and it has support for HTTP2 built-in.